# link index printing blank python

Tags: python

I couldn't find a thread that was related. I am working on a seasons lab. I need to be able to take a month and day and print the season. It needs to print invalid for days that are not calendars days and strange inputs. I decided to use lists, but they keep printing out blank outputs. I am not sure where my code is just ending.

---

```html
input_month = str(input()).lower() # make user input a lower case string
input_month = input_month.replace(' ', '') # remove spaces in user input
input_day = int(input()) # make user input a number

# list of seasons
spring = ['march', 'april', 'may', 'june']
summer = ['june', 'july', 'august', 'september']
autumn = ['september', 'october', 'november', 'december']
winter = ['december', 'january', 'february', 'march']
season = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn', 'Winter']

if input_month in spring: # "march" or 'april' or 'may' or 'june':
    if (input_month == spring[0]) and (31 >= input_day > 19):
       season = season[0]
       print(season)
   elif (input_month == spring[0]) and (1 <= input_day < 19):
       season = season[3]
       print(season)
    elif (input_month == spring[3]) and (1 <= input_day < 21):
       season = season[0]
       print(season)
    elif (input_month == spring[3]) and (31 <= input_day > 21):
       season = season[1]
       print(season)
    elif (input_month == spring[1] or input_month == spring[2]) and (1 <= input_day <= 31):
       season = season[0]
       print(season)
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

---

I am receiving this output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCmmR.png)

---

When I place a breakpoint then debug and step over, the input march 19, is just skipping over the elif statement:

```html
elif (input_month == spring[0]) and (1 <= input_day < 19):
     season = season[3]
     print(season)
```

---

I am really confused as to why when I use the calculator thing (evaluate in debug?, it saying that the statement:

```html
(input_month == spring[0]) and (1 <= input_day < 19)
```

, is false.

my interpretation (the input_month is march and input_day is 19):

if the input_month is the same as index 0 in spring list, which is 'march' and the input_day is between 1 (including 1) and input_day is less than 19... I think this is true so it should have stepped down in the elif statement.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4pOH.png)

I am utterly confused on where my logic is wrong and I can't find anything, besides that 'and' might just stop my code. but it's still going. I am only in week 3 of my first course and I am not even sure If I am searching for the right terms. Well, I am pretty sure I am not searching for the right terms at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated along with any suggestions for terms to research.

Thanks in advance jam.

ADD**
Thank you for your help. I almost figured out the lad, it was me miss using < and > signs along with the way I used the word  'and' paired with me having things like December in two lists, etc. Now I am just having issues with -1, not printing invalid.

```html
elif input_month in autumn:
   if input_month == autumn[1]:
      if 1 <= input_day <= 31:
         season = season[3]
         print(season)
      else:
         print('Invalid')
   elif input_month == autumn[2]:
      if 1 <= input_day <= 30:
         season = season[2]
         print(season)
      else:
         print('Invalid')
   elif input_month == autumn[3]:
      if 1 <= input_day <= 20:
         season = season[2]
         print(season)
      elif 21 >= input_day <= 31:
         season = season[3]
         print(season)
      else:
         print('Invalid')
```

Comment: If, as you say, `input_day` is 19, why do you expect `input_day < 19` to evaluate as true? Clearly, `19 < 19` is false.

Comment: your conditionals for `season[0]` are `(31 >= input_day > 19)` and `(1 <= input_day < 19)` for the first and second statements. In this case your range doesn't contain `19` as it is either greater `>` or less `<` than `19`. one of them should be `<=` or `>=` to include `19` in the range.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I almost figured out the lad, it was me miss using < and > signs along with the way I used the word  'and' paired with me having things like December in two lists, etc. Now I am just having issues with -1, not printing invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The input month of "april" is not equal to anything in the spring list/array. the formatting is wrong somewhere.